# Push and pull value on callstack .net

Tags: c#, .net

I've done this before, so I know it can be done..(although badly documented) but forgot how. I've been searching for 2 hours now and can't find anything like it.

I want to push and pull values on the callstack, like so:

```
public void Method1()
{
    InsertMagicClassHere.Push("Key", 1);//or something
    Method2();
}

public void Method2()
{
   int value =  InsertMagicClassHere.Pull("Key");//or something
}
```

I need this parameter in nearly all my methods for logging.. and don't want to pass this 3 layers deep with arguments.

Comment: Why don't use arguments?

Comment: This seems like a really really bad idea...

Comment: I wouldn't expect a lot of answers to a question that appears to have no value when you're unwilling to explain why you need it...

Comment: I'm gonna ignore you and ask: Why do you want this? This is exactly what function parameters _are_.

Comment: This question reminds me of Forth.

Comment: I need this parameter in nearly all my methods for logging.. and don't want to pass this 3 layers deep with arguments.

Comment: OK Dude, I haven't voted to close, but it looks this question _WILL_ be closed if you don't explain what you're trying to do. Tell us what you're trying to achieve and we may well be able to give you a simple 2 line way of doing it. It could be you're misremembering what you did before. Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for does not exist. Moreover, it's not even clear what it's supposed to *do*.

Comment: Why not store it in a field or property then?

Comment: I did vote to close - if you want to achieve something put it it as title, so far there is no way to achieve what you want in normal C#. If you want to do something for logging just use exisitng library for that...

Comment: It cannot use a property or field because it's user dependent

Comment: @Flores: What you describe in your question does not make sense to others, because it isn't clear what it is that it *does*.

Comment: Great.. gets closed because nobody knows the answer.. in the meantime i've found it..

Comment: But now I can't share it because it is closed.

Comment: Btw .. It does exactly what I said it would.. Please reopen if you wan't to know the answer.. it's a great feature but not many people know this..

Comment: Voting to reopen in order to allow the OP to post the solution he fou nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. the answer is:

[CallContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx)

This works:

```
       public void Method1()
    {
        CallContext.SetData("Key", 1);
        Method2();
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        int value = (int)CallContext.GetData("Key");
    }
```

Like I said this is not a well known feature.. If you knew it, you would have known what I was referring to.

I think it's a cool feature, not many uses for it, but still..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Reflection.Emit; however, this is not how it works.

You can't really emit *inline* opcodes.

Instead, you can emit whole methods/classes and load them as 'temporary' assemblies. You then call into the emitted method.

Obligatory sample:

```
public void CreateMethod()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    AssemblyBuilder asmbuilder = this.GetAssemblyBuilder("MyAssembly");
    ModuleBuilder mbuilder = this.GetModule(asmbuilder);
    TypeBuilder tbuilder = this.GetTypeBuilder(mbuilder, "MyClass");

    Type[] tparams = { typeof(System.Int32), typeof(System.Int32) };
    MethodBuilder methodSum = this.GetMethod(tbuilder, "Sum", typeof(System.Single), 
                                                                 tparams);

    ILGenerator generator = methodSum.GetILGenerator();

    generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(System.Single));  
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);    
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);    
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Add_Ovf);    
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_R4);    
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);    

    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);    
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);        
}
```

So what you could do

1. take an existing method
2. disassemble it
3. write the code to emit a new method on the IL level (using Reflection.Emit)
4. load the emitted assembly
5. call into your code.

See these articles for good starters:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DLR.aspx
- MSDN: [using Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx)

Comment: No.. my method was way simpler.. really like 2 lines of code.. must be something else..

Comment: @flores Was it asp.net? Maybe you where pushing it into the app or session cache?

Comment: It was asp.net yes.. pretty sure it wasnt session.. what do you meen with app cache?

Comment: Session is per session caching, Application is per application caching. ie `Application["myKey"]=new MyObj();`

Comment: Don't you think making sure people understand the execution context of your problem is important to getting an accurate answer? You could have at least added the asp.net tag.

Comment: Because i'm sure it isn't asp.net specific.